# IOS Application automatic resize content to fit different screen size

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, layout, uiview, display

I'm going to implement an ios application design. The design is made with iphone 5 screen size in mind (640 x 1136 px).

I want to automatically resize all the content to fit screen size of the display it will be running on, including: font size, bitmap size, subview size.

Ideally I want to code only once that assume the width of the device is 320 points regardless the actual width of the device. Iphone 6 and 6s have bigger displays but still have the same aspect ratio.

For example if I create a box of UIView in my viewcontroller:

```
UIView *box = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10)];
box.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubView:box];
```

will always draw a red box spanning full width of the screen regardless device screen size (in iphone 6 & 6s). I do most of the visual component and layouting using code like above including for creating UILabel, etc.

Basically it is functioning like 'display zoom' feature in iphone 6, 6plus, but only for this application. (not globally)

What trick to do to get the desired result ? If possible I don't want to use autolayout.

Thanks,

Comment: You can calculate your screen width and height and adjust your views accordingly, or you can add constraints in code, have a look at [NSLayoutConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/)

Comment: You say you don't want to use autolayout, but seriously, use autolayout.

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't want to use autolayout because I will need to set a lot of constraints. in the other hand what I need is just to 'stretch' the view to fit the device screen size. This way I will only need to set x,y,width,height for all the subviews in iphone5 screen size, and it will (hopefully) be stretched to fill the whole screen for iphone 6 and 6+ (same aspect ratio).

Comment: I was thinking to use transform (CGAffineTransform) to scale them but it is a bitmap scaling, will make some defect if bitmaps/icons subviews are upscaled

Comment: You can use the older springs and struts auto resize approach, but autolayout has been around for 5 years now and makes it much easier to handle all of the different display sizes

Answer (score -1):

@night_coder, i am not sure about what ur trying to say, but based up on my understand i am answering you.

You can go for Visual Layouts (If you trying programatically)

or

you can go Auto Resizing, by disabling auto layouts and subviews (If you trying threw story board)